# Spring property setter for Map exception

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I am using spring 3.0 and trying a property setter injection for `Map<String ,String>`

Here are the configs and setter method:
Spring configuration is as below:

```
<bean name="geocoder" class="com.g1.component.igeocode.RemoteGeocoder" >
         <property name="geocoderConverters">
            <map>
                <entry key="Default" value="com.g1.component.igeocode.mapmarker.DefaultGeocoderConverter"/>
                <entry key="4.8.1.51" value="com.g1.component.igeocode.mapmarker.GeocoderConverter_v4_8_1_51"/>
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

RemoteGeocoder.java

```
private Map<String, String> geocoderConverters;

    public Map<String, String> getGeocoderConverters() {
        return geocoderConverters;
    }

    public void setGeocoderConverters(Map<String, String> geocoderConverters) {
        this.geocoderConverters = geocoderConverters;
    }
```

But i am getting below error at runtime:

```
Error creating bean with name 'geocoder' defined in URL [file:/E:/Spectrum code/Spectrum 7/cdqplatform/platform/server/dist/target/g1server/server/app/tmp/igeocode-global-7.0.car-1643772799809108204-contents/resourcestage-config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'geocoderConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Method invoker set on com.g1.component.igeocode.RemoteGeocoder@12a6f35
```

Can someone please throw insight on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try it with `Map<Object, Object>` instead.

Comment: I tried this but this also doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmmm, I know for a fact that this can work with `setXXX( Map<Object,Object> map )`, `<map key-type="java.lang.String">` and `<entry key="abc" value-ref="beanRef"/>` so I suspect your problem isn't with the Spring part.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying keys and values type to `String`:

```
<property name="geocoderConverters">
    <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="Default" value="com.g1.component.igeocode.mapmarker.DefaultGeocoderConverter"/>
        <entry key="4.8.1.51" value="com.g1.component.igeocode.mapmarker.GeocoderConverter_v4_8_1_51"/>
    </map>
</property>
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working. I also tried declaring map as Map instead of Map<String,String> but still not picking it. Not sure what spring expect as setter method signature for Maps.

Comment: Ok try to change your Map to HashMap and add "map-class="java.util.HashMap"

Comment: I tried following : <util:map id="converters" map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
       <entry key="Default" value="com.g1.component.igeocode.mapmarker.DefaultGeocoderConverter" />
       <entry key="4.8.1.51" value="com.g1.component.igeocode.mapmarker.GeocoderConverter_v4_8_1_51" />
 </util:map>. Also changed the property to HashMap. Tried various permutations but still facing same issue :(